# How does Excel compute the resolution of the metafiles it generates when copying a range "as shown on screen"?

Tags: c#, excel, copy, metafile

I have some C# code I got from http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/572657-net-clipboard-metafiles that copies a cell range under the following two settings:

- *As shown on screen,*
- *As shown when printed*.

When I look at the resulting metafile's resolution (which is documented as `Gets the resolution, in pixels-per-inch, of this Image object`), I get different values depending on the copy method.

- With the *As shown when printed* option, the resolution is 600, which I believe corresponds to the DPI settings I have in Excel.
- With the *As shown on screen* setting, it spits out something like `Metafile.VerticalResolution = 72.08107` and `Metafile.HorizontalResolution = 71.95952`. On other machines, I've seen this value vary a lot (values around 111, 130, etc.).

Zoom level doesn't seem to affect this. From what I've observed, the values stay consistent on a single machine, but may differ from machine to machine.

Can anyone explain the logic Excel follows when computing the resolution of the metafile in *As shown on screen* mode?

After changing the windows resolution and measuring the metafile resolutions, here is the table I generated (hope it looks formatted correctly):

```
Width   Height  HorizontalResolution    VerticalResolution
1680    1050        71.95952                72.08107
1600    1024        72.05672                72.04874
1600    900         72.05672                71.88678
1360    768         71.96666                71.98228
1280    1024        71.9292                 72.04874
1280    960         71.9292                 71.9292
1280    800         71.9292                 72.05672
1280    768         71.9292                 71.98228
1280    720         71.9292                 71.99999
1152    864         72.07093                71.95278
1088    612         71.96666                71.96666
1024    768         72.04874                71.98228
960     600         71.9292                 71.88678
800     600         72.05672                71.88678
```

After running a similar procedure on a virtual machine (same physical machine), these are the results. A bit more volatile than the physical machine itself. This data might not be useful, but thought I'd provide it anyways.

```
Width   Height  HorizontalResolution    VerticalResolution
1680    1050    133.35                  111.125
1280    800     101.6                   84.66666
1024    768     81.27999                81.27999
800     600     63.5                    63.5
```

Comment: These values should come from the device context used to create the metafile. Apparently, Excel does not pass a screen device context (as you would get the default 96 DPI then). Or maybe you're connecting to the machines through a Terminal Server session? It's known to have an effect on the resolution returned by screen device contexts.

Comment: Some of the machines I have tested it on are virtual machines, but I've had it tested on other people's computers, and the values do vary. I just haven't been able to figure out what Excel does internally to get that value. (The main issue is I have my own separate copy/paste method, and my size values are not matching the ones when you do it natively through Excel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### My Hypothesis

I believe this has to do with running a non-native resolution on an LCD monitor. In "the old days" CRTs didn't have a native resolution per se. So the computer was unaware of any preferred resolution for a given monitor size or aspect ratio. With newer digital displays (LCD) the computer is now aware of the preferred resolution and aspect ratio for your display if properly installed. My windows 7 machine shows "recommended" next to my LCD's native resolution and then shows the other 2 equal aspect ratio resolutions in black, with the remaining "mismatches" being unlabelled but selectable (resulting in the squished or stretched look that I hate to see on other peoples computers!).

The default DPIs of 96 and 120 in windows were established back in the CRT days. My windows 7 machine doesn't even say DPI anymore it just says 'smaller', 'medium', 'larger'.

Either way, when you buy an LCD monitor that is say 1920x1080 or 1920x1200 but set the display resolution to something smaller, you result in a conversion factor. In the case of the non-matching horizontal and vertical resolutions close to 72, your non-native display resolution may not be exactly the same scaling factor vertically as it is horizontally resulting in this small discrepancy.

### How To Test My Hypothesis

On each of your test machines record the operating systems configured resolution and the displays native resolution. See if the ratio between these two is close to the ratio between your metafile 'as on screen' vs either 96 or 120dpi. I would prefer you conduct this test on physical machines to simply rule out the possibility of further scaling with remote desktop or virtual machine drivers.

If the solution isn't immediately apparent, take a step further and record the operating and control panel settings for DPI or 'smaller', 'medium' and 'larger'. Windows XP may behave differently than Windows Vista/Windows 7.

You could also re-run the test on the same physical machine several times, adjusting the configured display resolution between tests and observe any changes. If my hypothesis is correct you should see a different metafile resolution for each configured display resolution on the same physical machine/display combination and this result should be predictable and repeatable (returning to the first resolution should return to the same metafile resolution)

### EDIT #1

I found an excellent article that discusses physical DPI vs logical DPI. Have a read of this: [Where does 96 DPI come from in Windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fontblog/archive/2005/11/08/490490.aspx)

So now the next test I'd recommend is changing displays! Do you have a different brand/size/resolution LCD monitor available for testing? You don't need quite so many lines as your first test above as we've established the various resolutions tend to produce a very similar DPI for the same display. Just test maybe a couple common resolutions including the display's native resolution and 1024x768 as a "baseline" for comparison.

Also while poking around in Windows 7, I did find the "Set Custom Text Size (DPI)" link in control panel->display which included a "Use Windows XP Style DPI scaling" option. While I don't think this is the primary concern, curiosity makes me interested in its effect, so I thought I'd mention it.

### EDIT #2 - SOLVED!

The resolution you are seeing in your metafiles is the physical DPI of your monitor. I'll post some C# code here for you to test yourself:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

public enum DeviceCap
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Device driver version
    /// </summary>
    DRIVERVERSION = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// Device classification
    /// </summary>
    TECHNOLOGY = 2,
    /// <summary>
    /// Horizontal size in millimeters
    /// </summary>
    HORZSIZE = 4,
    /// <summary>
    /// Vertical size in millimeters
    /// </summary>
    VERTSIZE = 6,
    /// <summary>
    /// Horizontal width in pixels
    /// </summary>
    HORZRES = 8,
    /// <summary>
    /// Vertical height in pixels
    /// </summary>
    VERTRES = 10,
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of bits per pixel
    /// </summary>
    BITSPIXEL = 12,
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of planes
    /// </summary>
    PLANES = 14,
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of brushes the device has
    /// </summary>
    NUMBRUSHES = 16,
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of pens the device has
    /// </summary>
    NUMPENS = 18,
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of markers the device has
    /// </summary>
    NUMMARKERS = 20,
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of fonts the device has
    /// </summary>
    NUMFONTS = 22,
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of colors the device supports
    /// </summary>
    NUMCOLORS = 24,
    /// <summary>
    /// Size required for device descriptor
    /// </summary>
    PDEVICESIZE = 26,
    /// <summary>
    /// Curve capabilities
    /// </summary>
    CURVECAPS = 28,
    /// <summary>
    /// Line capabilities
    /// </summary>
    LINECAPS = 30,
    /// <summary>
    /// Polygonal capabilities
    /// </summary>
    POLYGONALCAPS = 32,
    /// <summary>
    /// Text capabilities
    /// </summary>
    TEXTCAPS = 34,
    /// <summary>
    /// Clipping capabilities
    /// </summary>
    CLIPCAPS = 36,
    /// <summary>
    /// Bitblt capabilities
    /// </summary>
    RASTERCAPS = 38,
    /// <summary>
    /// Length of the X leg
    /// </summary>
    ASPECTX = 40,
    /// <summary>
    /// Length of the Y leg
    /// </summary>
    ASPECTY = 42,
    /// <summary>
    /// Length of the hypotenuse
    /// </summary>
    ASPECTXY = 44,
    /// <summary>
    /// Shading and Blending caps
    /// </summary>
    SHADEBLENDCAPS = 45,

    /// <summary>
    /// Logical pixels inch in X
    /// </summary>
    LOGPIXELSX = 88,
    /// <summary>
    /// Logical pixels inch in Y
    /// </summary>
    LOGPIXELSY = 90,

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of entries in physical palette
    /// </summary>
    SIZEPALETTE = 104,
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of reserved entries in palette
    /// </summary>
    NUMRESERVED = 106,
    /// <summary>
    /// Actual color resolution
    /// </summary>
    COLORRES = 108,

    // Printing related DeviceCaps. These replace the appropriate Escapes
    /// <summary>
    /// Physical Width in device units
    /// </summary>
    PHYSICALWIDTH = 110,
    /// <summary>
    /// Physical Height in device units
    /// </summary>
    PHYSICALHEIGHT = 111,
    /// <summary>
    /// Physical Printable Area x margin
    /// </summary>
    PHYSICALOFFSETX = 112,
    /// <summary>
    /// Physical Printable Area y margin
    /// </summary>
    PHYSICALOFFSETY = 113,
    /// <summary>
    /// Scaling factor x
    /// </summary>
    SCALINGFACTORX = 114,
    /// <summary>
    /// Scaling factor y
    /// </summary>
    SCALINGFACTORY = 115,

    /// <summary>
    /// Current vertical refresh rate of the display device (for displays only) in Hz
    /// </summary>
    VREFRESH = 116,
    /// <summary>
    /// Horizontal width of entire desktop in pixels
    /// </summary>
    DESKTOPVERTRES = 117,
    /// <summary>
    /// Vertical height of entire desktop in pixels
    /// </summary>
    DESKTOPHORZRES = 118,
    /// <summary>
    /// Preferred blt alignment
    /// </summary>
    BLTALIGNMENT = 119
}

private void GetScreenInfo()
{
    IntPtr sdc = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        //Get the Screen Device Context
        sdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);

        // Get the Screen Devive Context Capabilities Information
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Size: {0} mm X {1} mm", GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.HORZSIZE), GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.VERTSIZE)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Desktop Resolution: {0}x{1}", GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPHORZRES), GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPVERTRES)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Logical DPI: {0}x{1}", GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.LOGPIXELSX), GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.LOGPIXELSY)));

        //Remember: Convert Millimeters to Inches 25.4mm = 1 inch
        double PhsyicalDPI_X = GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPHORZRES) * 25.4 / GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.HORZSIZE);
        double PhsyicalDPI_Y = GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPVERTRES) * 25.4 / GetDeviceCaps(sdc, (int)DeviceCap.VERTSIZE);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Physical DPI: {0}x{1}", PhsyicalDPI_X, PhsyicalDPI_Y));

    }
    finally
    {
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, sdc);
    }
}
```

This code on my display outputs the following:

- Size: 677 mm X 381 mm
- Desktop Resolution: 1920x1080
- Logical DPI: 96x96
- Physical DPI: 72.0354505169867x72

Notice both the logical and physical DPI? Does that physical DPI look familiar? It all makes sense after reading that article about 72dpi reflecting 1pt=1px. Give this code a try on your various test machines and let me know how it goes! (FYI, I ran this code in a C# winforms app, a console app *should* be able to get the screen device context, but maybe not...)

Comment: It seems changing the resolution made a slight difference. I've edited the table I generated into the original question. I'll investigate more now that I have some data. Also, it seems like changing the low, medium, high settings didn't make a difference.

Comment: Very interesting. So that table was all one machine? Was the native resolution for your display 1680x1050? Its interesting to me that none of the results are a plain integer and that they all center around 72 for you. I would take from that data the resolution is changing the aspect ratio but not the scale.

Comment: @Shark take a look at my edit in the answer. I think you need to try another physical display as the next step in diagnosing this issue.

Comment: Yes, it works! Tested this out on the VM's and it works on that too. There's sometimes a small discrepancy on the .0001 value or so, but I'll chalk that up to rounding.